# gwt multi-page application

Tags: gwt

I have a multipage application which needs to manually switched from one page to another. could it be done in GWT since it is targeted towards single page application. I am learning from the Google code and online forums but could not find any application which had multi-pages not linked by a common entry-point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GWT has support for "pages" within application via URL [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) (FI), i.e. `http://www.yourhost.vom/main#pagename`, where "pagename" is a fragment identifier representing a "page" within your app.

This "pages" (note that browser never really reloads the page, so GWT app stays the same), have full history support and are bookmarkable.

NOTE: throughout GWT docs fragment identifier is sometimes referred to as place token or history token.

1. Enable [history support](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) by adding an iframe to your host page:

   ```
   <iframe src="javascript:''" 
           id="__gwt_historyFrame" 
           style="width:0;height:0;border:0">
   </iframe>
   ```
2. Register a ValueChangeHandler to be notified when FI (page) changes: `History.addValueChangeHandler(..)`. Within this handler you put a logic that displays the new page.
3. Go to a particular page by calling `History.newItem("newpage")` (without #)
4. You can even pass "parameters" to page, by dividing fragment identifier into sub parts: for example "#edit/user4". Just parse this FI, invoke code that shows edit page and pass "user4" to it. You can use any character to divide FI into a "page" part and "parameter" part (I use "/" here). To see this in real life: open a message in gmail and look at URL.

Comment: any examples for this multi-page application. how would you implement a normal <a href ="page2.html"> in gwt or make only static pages without parameter parsing

Comment: There is no static pages in GWT app. You can create one on your server, but this means leaving GWT app. A normal anchor is done like this: `<a href="#page2">, where you handle "page2" in your code an show what you want.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use GWT to switch pages, the resulting code will be slow and suboptimal, with the pages taking longer to load.