# is it possible to create many ui Forms (with UIBinder) with GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, uibinder

Actually, for my project I have two predefined HTML files (one for login and one for the application).

I have to use GWT and until now, the application(with its html file) and the login page are working well.

However I need to assemble the two modules, and I am wondering how can I make call from one html file to another with gwt? and should I define two different UIbinders, or I have to put everything in only one (if it is the last solution, how can I do it?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this all in one application, then you should have one html host page and two UiBinder files. One for main app page and one for login. You can programmatically show the login "page" when required.

You might want to read how to mage "pages" within GWT app: [gwt multi-page application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984775/gwt-multi-page-application)

Comment: Do I really need to use history? my application don't really need saving history.

Answer (score 0):

Just create one html file and one module. In the html file, have two divs, such as:

```
<div id="login"/>
<div id="application"/>
```

In the module, import the Java classes that you had used for the application and the login screen. And then in your module's onModuleLoad() create the login and application panels, and add them like this:

```
RootPanel.get("login").add(loginPanel);
RootPanel.get("application").add(applicationPanel);
```

They should work just fine together. HTH.

Comment: I can't use only one html file, those two files are proposed by the company I work with, and I can't combine them (not the same style at all)

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean "how can I make call from one html file to another"? What's "calling"? What do you want to see on the browser exactly?

Comment: I have login.html (with its uibuilder UserForm) and search.html (with ists UIBuilder SearchForm). What I need is that, when I click on a button or hyperlink or... from login page, search.html is charged on the browser and SearchForm is called. I can put some of my code here if it helps understand my question.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. In the Login module, once the login is successful, you can call Window.Location.replace("search.html"); in your GWT code to make the browser go to search.html. You can also do it after a delay, and display something like "login successful, redirecting to the search page" etc. I don't think you can do the redirect on the server code, since it's just an RPC call. Make sure that the search module allows only authenticated users.

Comment: that's what i did, but when i use Window.Location.replace("search.html"), the html page is loaded but not the SearchForm module.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't make sense to me. I'm guessing the SearchForm module gets loaded when you go to search.html otherwise? Are they really the same URLs? Can you try hitting F5 after you get redirected to search.html and see if SearchForm loads then?